# How to change htaccess to access symfony web directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony

I am running symfony2 in Windows7 and Xampp:

`http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/symfony`

How do I change web/.htaccess file to access symfony using the link below?

`http://localhost/app_dev.php/hello/symfony`

the default .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried adding `Rewrite RewriteBase /symfony/web/` or `RewriteBase symfony/web/` then `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` and also tried restarting apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteBase /symfony/web/ OR RewriteBase symfony/web/
```

And can I do the same in Nginx with Reverse proxy? How to change to access without `symfony/web`?

Comment: This is close to no research effort. There has to be tutorials/documentation for this.

Comment: @Olof Edler I am new to htaccess, i checked tutorial somewhere, but dont know how htaccess works

Comment: @r4: "There has to be tutorials" is also close to no research effort; I've just spent an hour looking for such a tutorial, and couldn't find one; if you know better, you would have posted an actual link to such a tutorial. Wish I could -1 your comment, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried add `127.0.0.1 www.mysymfony.com.localhost`
into etc/hosts
add the following into httpd.conf

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration<br>
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName www.mysymfony.com.localhost
  DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\web"
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

access this link
`http://www.mysymfony.com.localhost/app_dev.php/demo/hello/symfony`
it gives an error,doesnt have this link

Comment: @m2mdas actually it doesnt work, I did restart apache, and even the system, it says No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: @m2mdas after change httpd.conf and etc/hosts the old  link [http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/symfony](http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/symfony)  still works

Comment: Remove `RewriteBase` line from `.htaccess` and try. Also form your `httpd.conf` I think server name would be `www.mysymfony.com.localhost`.