# Symfony2 production script issues

Tags: php, symfony

I build CMS script with Symfony2 framework. And I want to make that script open-source. But I have a problem. How can I zip whole script for script and then when end-user download that archive and extract on root folder on his server, and when go to the his domain www.something.com to show script, not folder structure? How to make that end-user have not to type web/app.php in address? What is htaccess command for that?

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this, if the user has full control over their server, is to point the vhost to the "web" folder rather than the project root. Therefore, I wonder, are you specifically talking about shared hosting?

Comment: Yes, my target group are users with shared hosting. I need to provide script with htaccess file, and to provide that end-users doesn't have to change and code anything. Can I provide that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change htaccess to access symfony web directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063089/how-to-change-htaccess-to-access-symfony-web-directory)